# Connection timeout using windows and TCP

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, freeze

I am using `ffmpeg` on windows.

When my camera is not available during connecting I get no error - `ffmpeg` hangs forever.

Using Linux `ffmpeg` exits after a few seconds with an error.

Is there a flag I need to set for windows?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a flag I need to set for windows?

There are 2 possibilities `-timeout` and `-stimeout`:

> - `-timeout`
>
>   Set maximum timeout (in seconds) to wait for incoming connections.
>
>   A value of -1 mean infinite (default). This option implies the
>   `rtsp_flags` set to `listen.
>
>   `reorder_queue_size`
>
>   Set number of packets to buffer for handling of reordered packets.
> - `-stimeout`
>
>   Set socket TCP I/O timeout in micro seconds.
>
> See the RTSP protocol documentation for more info:
> http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

Source: [[FFmpeg-user] How do I set a timeout for an RTSP source?](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-June/022087.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found that ffmpeg compiled with cygwin will not be hung and will exit after timeout.

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/ffmpeg.html
https://github.com/q3aql/ffmpeg-builds

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228561)